# How to directly upload .doc file from Google Drive to R?

Tags: r

I saved my data as code in my Google Drive.

```
data.frame(
  season=rep(2023, 24L),
  crop=rep("Soybean", 24L),
  plot=rep(seq(1,8,by=1),rep(c(5L,1L),each=4L)),
  treatment=c("tr1", "tr2", "tr3", "tr3", "tr5", 
              "tr1", "tr2", "tr3", "tr3", "tr5", 
              "tr1", "tr2", "tr3", "tr3", "tr5", 
              "tr1", "tr2", "tr3", "tr3", "tr5", 
              "control","control", "control", 
              "control"),
  grain_yield=c(32.2, 5, 4.3, 1, 8.7, 25.6, 35.7, 
              29.2, 39.9, 20.7, 15.5, 23.2, 44.6,
              45, 32.4, 20.5, 35.2, 37.3, 9.6,16.8,
              103.2, 60.8, 33, 66.2))
```

Because I used to lose my Excel files, from now on, I'd like to save all my data as code in Google Drive. I saved this code as below: https://docs.google.com/document/d/16hMJxXY7zlFp0XuV3H-mb8YOkrTVK386DA_IAvMLKUs

When analyzing data, I want to directly upload this code from Google Drive to R. I found several answers but can't clearly find the answer I want.

I found one answer in Stackoverflow: [read file from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72903262/read-file-from-google-drive), but this code does not work in my case `read.csv("https://docs.google.com/document/d/16hMJxXY7zlFp0XuV3H-mb8YOkrTVK386DA_IAvMLKUs/pub?output=csv")`

Could you please let me know how to upload the .doc data from Goold Drive to R?

Thanks,

Comment: You have `https://https://` in the a URL. Besides that, appending `pub?output=csv`  only works for Google Spreadsheets that have already been published,  but in your case it's a text document with R source code, not something that `read.csv()` could handle even when content gets downloaded correctly. If you get a Google Drive (not Docs) link for that file, this might be somewhat useful - https://stackoverflow.com/q/75528811/646761

Though note that there are packages like https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/  and https://pins.rstudio.com/ (supports gdrive).

Comment: @margusl thank you for your comment. I corrected the URL. Maybe, for doc file, it would be necessary to download first and upload to R, not directly uploading from Google Drive to R. What I wanted was to save the data as code in my web note and manage it as a list so that I can assess whenever I want, avoiding the change to lose the original data file. Thanks!!